# Trying to block website

Tags: linux, hosts

I have Linux and i try to block website and i have followed this kind of way to block website in my computer..

Steps to block websites in Linux
Open terminal shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + T</kbd>.
Type `sudo gedit /etc/hosts` and type Ubuntu password.
Then at the bottom of file. Type each website's name you want to block like this:

I try to block website called: `chat27.co.za`:

```
127.0.0.1 www.chat27.co.za
127.0.0.1 https://chat27.co.za/
127.0.0.1 www.chat27.co.za/ 
127.0.0.1 chat27.co.za/
127.0.0.1 www.chat27.co.za
127.0.0.1 www.chat27.co.za/
```

But it hasn't blocked the website...

Terminal says

```
(gedit 4716), Warning**, 19:07.42.840. Set document metadata attribute medata: gedit- spell language not supported.
```

Previously it was blocking websites when I wrote it but now it doesn't do that... I have tried to write in hosts/ etc in different ways that... What's the problem? How can I block that website?

Comment: It could be interesting to have your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, especially the `hosts:` line. I have `hosts: files dns` which means that the `/etc/hosts` is read first, then the DNS is asked.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *very* dated instruction that you're following there. It assumes that the program you use to access the website (your browser?) asks your operating system (or, rather, libc) to convert domains names like "www.chat27.co.za" to IP addresses.

No browser does that by default anymore. (for a few years already actually!)

Browsers have internal resolvers (e.g. to enable things like DNS over TLS, and to decouple from often questionable DNS configurations of hosts, like exactly the one you want to do here), or they go through other mechanisms ("NSS"), which might or might not care about /etc/hosts; chances are your system doesn't. I don't think that's a bad thing.

So, what you want to achieve here doesn't work that way.

(also, you can enter *domain names* there, not *URLs*.)

Generally, blocking at the hostname level doesn't work well: the user just needs to change the name resolving method their browser uses, and then they're free to access the website again.

---

> (gedit 4716), Warning**, 19:07.42.840. Set document metadata attribute medata: gedit- spell language not supported.

Completely unrelated. This is fully irrelevant; it's just your editor telling you that it doesn't know in which human language the file you're editing is written, in case you wanted to spellcheck it...

Comment: FWIW this does not seem to be the case for Windows - in my experience, browsers on there still use the `hosts` file.